# find a pair in set c++

Tags: c++, iterator, find, set

if I have a set which contains pairs of int,

```
set<pair<int,int> > cells;
```

how can I find whether a pair exits in the set using 'find'. I can use 'find' for set with one value but cant do it for a pair.

I am trying like,

```
 cells.insert(make_pair(1,1));
 set<int,int>::iterator it;
 it=cells.find(pair<int,int>(1,1));

error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = cells.std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find<std::pair<int, int>, std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >((*(const key_type*)(& std::pair<int, int>((* &1), (* &1)))))'|
```

Has anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your set is a set of a pair of integers`std::pair<int,int>`, instead of just `<int,int>`. Changing that fixes your code. If you are using c++11 or later you can just use the auto keyword.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> p1(1,0);
    std::pair<int,int> p2(2,1);
    std::set<std::pair<int,int>> s;
    s.insert(p1);
    s.insert(p2);
    auto it = s.find(p1);
    std::cout << it->first << "," << it->second <<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a typo/misunderstanding about the type to be used for `it`. You need to use:

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> cells;
cells.insert(std::make_pair(1,1));
std::set<std::pair<int,int>>::iterator it; // here was the problem
it=cells.find(std::pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

In order to avoid these kind of mistakes you may use `auto`:

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>> cells;
cells.insert(std::make_pair(1,1));
auto it =cells.find(std::pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

If you have to separate the definition and the use of `it`:

```
decltype(cells)::iterator it;
it=cells.find(std::pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/9eba)